# Drawing pixels to screen, cross-platform

Tags: c, user-interface, cross-platform

In short: all I want is to display pixel data on screen in the most fundamental way possible, without losing cross-platform compatibility.

I know similar questions have been asked before, but they didn't seem to go in the direction I'm looking.

Basically, I'm making my own little game library, which I intend to use for my own 2D pixel-art games. All pixel-handling I take care of by myself, and now I've been looking around for the absolute minimal solution to getting up a window, listening to its events (mouse, keyboard, window-events) and drawing my pixels to it. A bonus would be if the library could handle threads and/or audio.

I don't need any OpenGL support at this stage, and I'm not sure I ever will. I don't really need any features apart from those mentioned at all. Should I start digging in the Windows, X11 and OSX APIs by myself, or is there a truly minimalist framework out there somewhere? Is making my own platform independent minimalist framework actually hard work? If it's not a that big of a deal I might just look into that solution out of sheer curiosity.

If you have any insight on making my own vs. finding something useful, I'm all ears.

Thanks!

EDIT: In short...

Comment: How about SDL? There are several [GUI libraries](http://www.libsdl.org/libraries.php?category=14) for it, like Cegui.

Comment: Your question is kind of confusing. Are you looking for a native cross-platform GUI framework (like QT?) or something can can be plugged into a renderer (like Cegui or TWL)?

Comment: Well, I guess its not strange its confusing. I'm not entirely sure how to describe my problem. I basically want to display pixel information on the screen in the most fundamental way possible, without giving up cross-platform compatibility. I'll take a look at Cegui and TWL. Thanks.

Comment: Use SDL or Allegro. A textured quad in OpenGL is also an option for graphics, but you would need additional libraries for keyboard/mouse/etc...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most complete, yet simple library is [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/). It is cross platform across Windows, Mac, Linux and more. With it you can:

- create your game window (or make your game full screen)
- handle keyboard and mouse events
- access individual pixels (add [SDL_Draw](http://sdl-draw.sourceforge.net/) for functions to draw pixels, lines, circles, etc.)
- sound effect playback
- background music playback
- threading functions
- OpenGL support, should you realize that you need it.

Note that your idea of handling the drawing your own way by addressing individual pixels may not give you good performance unless your game is very simple. I would keep the door open to OpenGL and the wonderful world of hardware acceleration.

Comment: After looking around a lot I found this to be the better solution. Thanks you all for your time!